# WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, cas

I am trying to run a docker image of CAS[dockerscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Z15.png), now I am facing a issues that indicating these errors:

```
2022-05-27 08:05:17,985 WARN [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext] - <Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server>

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)

Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server

at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)

at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)

at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)

at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)

at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)

at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)

at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164)

at org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication.main(CasWebApplication.java:52)

... 8 more

Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server

at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43)

at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)

... 21 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:238)

at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282)

at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213)

... 23 more

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed

at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1075)

at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:234)

... 25 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /etc/cas/thekeystore (No such file or directory)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:234)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1313)

at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1072)

... 27 more

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/cas/thekeystore (No such file or directory)

at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)

at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.catalina.startup.CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.getResource(CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.java:118)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:199)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:207)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:283)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)

... 33 more
```

If anyone knows how to fix this please help me ...... thanks.....

Comment: (1) use 'code' format ({} button or control-K or 3 backticks before and after) for computer data so it's not comletely unreadable (I fixed for you) and _don't_ doublespace (I didn't fix, too much work) (2) ultimate cause is `FileNotFoundException: /etc/cas/thekeystore ...` -- you are trying to use a file that isn't there; either put the correct file there, or change the filename to a correct one.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you for pointing out the error there, I will be looking into this part.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you, I have looked into it, and I added thekeystore file with some generated key, its now working! thank for pointing out my mistake thanksssssssssssssssssssssss